# Updating specific row on a table PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been trying to create a CRUD for a project and everything works great, except the update part. When I click the href of the edit of the specified row it does appear on the input fields. However when I click the editbtn the variables of the specific row are not updated and i am redirected where I was and the url gives me ?user=edited meaning that it went through the decision but for some reason they werent updated.
In my database there is one table(users) with the following rows user_id, user_uid, user_email, user_pwd, user_status and user_level. I am fairly new to php so i was hoping that you could pinpoint my mistake/s.

The connection to the database

dbh.inc.php

```
<?php
$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "username";
$dbPassword = "*******";
$dbName = "username_Project";
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName );
?>
```

The index

admin_panel_users.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    $update = true;
    $record= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=$id");
    if ($record == 1 ) {
        $n = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
        $uid = $n['user_uid'];
        $email = $n['user_email'];
        $pwd = $n['user_pwd'];
        $status = $n['user_status'];
        $level = $n['user_level'];
   }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 .....
</head>
<body>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users");?>
<table border='2'>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Password</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Level</th>
<th>Actions</th>
</tr>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['user_uid'];?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['user_email'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['user_pwd'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['user_status'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['user_level'];?></td>
<td>
<a href="admin_panel_users.php?edit=<?php echo $row['user_id']; >" 
class="edit_btn">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
<a href="includes/deleteusers.inc.php?user_id=<?php echo $row['user_id'];>">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
 <form class="something" action="includes/addusers.inc.php" method="POST">
 <td><input type="text" name="uid" class="uid" placeholder="Username" 
 value="<?php echo $uid; ?>"></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Email" 
 value="<?php echo $email; ?>"></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="pwd" class="pwd" placeholder="Password" 
 value="<?php echo $pwd; ?>"></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="status" class="status" placeholder="Status" 
 value="<?php echo $status; ?>"></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="level" class="level" placeholder="Level" 
 value="<?php echo $level; ?>"></td>
 <td>
 <?php if ($update == true): ?>
 <button type="submit" name="update" class="updatebtn">
 <span class="glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp;</button>
 <?php else: ?>
 <button type="submit" name="submit8" class="addbtnuser">
 <span class ="glyphicon-plus"></span> &nbsp;</button>
 <?php endif ?>
 </td>
 </form>
 </tr>";
 </table>";
 <?php mysqli_close($conn); ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The functions

addusers.inc.php

```
 <?php
 include 'dbh.inc.php';
 $uid = "";
 $email = "";
 $pwd = "";
 $status = "";
 $level = "";
 $id = 0;
 $update = false;

 if (isset($_POST['submit8'])){
        //INSERTS INTO 
          ......
 }
 if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
     $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['uid']);
     $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['email']);
     $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['pwd']);
     $status = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['status']);
     $level = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn , $_POST['level']);
     $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_uid='$uid', user_email='$email', 
       user_pwd='$pwd', user_status='$status', user_level='$level' WHERE 
       user_id=$id";
     mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     header ("Location: ../admin_panel_users.php?user=edited");
     exit();
}
else{
     header("Location: ../admin_panel_users.php");
     exit();
}
```

Comment: Your code is subject to SQL injection. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: One of the most important parts of being a programmer is to develop the ability to *debug* the programs you write. Dumping a bunch of code and asking the internet to debug your program is not an efficient way.  Some suggestions:  test the return from mysqli_query, to see if the statement execution is successful.  echo/var_dump the contents of `$sql` before you send it to the database... and take that to another client (e.g. mysql command line) to test.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @SloanThrasher: OP code is calling `mysqli_real_escape_string`, the only value that isn't escaped is `$id`, and that is set to `0`, guaranteed to be safe. (Yes, I'd prefer to use prepared statements with bind placeholders, but OP has closed most of the avenues of exploits... what's left is `mysqli_real_escape_string` being broken, or some slippery mojo with characterset differences. Strictly speaking, this code isn't nearly as vulnerable to SQL Injection as it might be.)

Comment: I've seen many posts warning that using mysqli_real_escape_string isn't enough to prevent SQL injection. Using prepared statements eliminates that problem as well as quoting issues. While not as vulnerable as it would be without using that, it is still a better practice to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your addusers.inc.php, on the line that says:

`$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_uid='$uid', user_email='$email', 
       user_pwd='$pwd', user_status='$status', user_level='$level' WHERE 
       user_id=$id";`

It appears you didnt get the $id variable so as to update that particular row in your table. You defaulted it to 0 on line 8 of addusers.inc.php. So, it wont update any row at all because table rows start from 1 and increments.

On line 8, change it to 
`$id = $_GET['edit']` since you already passed it as a GET parameter here:
`<a href="admin_panel_users.php?edit=<?php echo $row['user_id']; >" 
class="edit_btn">`

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL text includes this:

```
WHERE user_id = $id
```

And `$id` is set to 0, so that's equivalent to

```
WHERE user_id = 0
```

---